# Arduino WeMos D1 R1 компилирует некорректно при попытке всего лишь зажечь светодиод

Tags: arduino

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я только начал изучать ардуино, у меня имеется плата Wemos D1 R1 и я хотел бы через нее зажечь светодиод однако что только не делал, ничего не помогает.Драйвер установлен, все параметры я по моему настроил корректно , если нет прошу помочь.Спасибо!

Comment: Где код? Где текст ошибки?

Comment: все ошибки внизу, если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Приведите код и текст ошибки в вопросе. Тут никто не будет гадать, что вы там понаписали.

Comment: Картинка с кодом, настройками и ошибкой почему то не загрузились, прошу прощения

Comment: Код и текст ошибок должны быть текстом ..

Comment: Если судить по куску текста ошибки, то возможно, что нужно установить python3.